# Connecting to WAMP server

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, wamp

I'm ultimately trying to access a mysql database through C# (using Visual Studio) that is on a WAMP server.  I'm running the WAMP server on localhost:81, and I tried to connect to the server with this:

```
string address = "http://localhost:81";
HostProxy = new ServiceHost(typeof(Server), new Uri(address));
```

But I was getting an `AddressAccessDeniedException`, so I reserved the address as instructed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/01/29/addressaccessdeniedexception-cause-and-solution.aspx).

But now I'm getting an `AddressAlreadyInUseException` because the address was reserved.

I'm running Visual Studio as an administrator. I've checked that the WAMP Server is running, and it is.

Comment: Windows firewall running? Open the port.

Comment: Btw you should place a @ b4 the "http://localhost:81", Also can you try running visual studio with admin rights?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".